# Nested grouping by multiple object properties (Highcharts categories)

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I need help in nested grouping. I'm currently learning highcharts and this is the formatting I need to form name and categories key value pairs.

I would like to group the data by school, gender and course. Below are the json codes I have.

```
[{"school":"Sunway","gender":"female","course":"BCS","Total":2},        
{"school":"Sunway","gender":"male","course":"BCS","Total":1},
{"school":"Sunway","gender":"female","course":"BICT","Total":1},
{"school":"Swinburne","gender":"female","course":"BCS","Total":2},
{"school":"Swinburne","gender":"male","course":"BCS","Total":3},
{"school":"Swinburne","gender":"female","course":"BICT","Total":1},
{"school":"Swinburne","gender":"male","course":"BICT","Total":2},
{"school":"UCTS","gender":"male","course":"BCS","Total":3},
{"school":"UCTS","gender":"female","course":"BICT","Total":1},
{"school":"UCTS","gender":"male","course":"BICT","Total":2}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{
    name: "Sunway",
    categories: [{
        gender: "female",
        categories: ["BICT", "BCS"]
    }, {
        name: "male",
        categories: ["BICT", "BCS"]
    }]
}, {
    name: "Swinburne",
    categories: [{
        name: "female",
        categories: ["BICT", "BCS"]
    }, {
        name: "male",
        categories: ["BICT", "BCS"]
    }]
}, {
    name: "UCTS",
    categories: [{
        name: "female",
        categories: ["BICT", "BCS"]
    }, {
        name: "male",
        categories: ["BICT", "BCS"]
    }]
}]
```

Thank you !! Much appreciated !!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/76bpLy5d/2/ live example of parsing your data, however I don't think this data will work correctly in Highcharts.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I am actually using another js framework for nested-categories which is called grouped-catgories.js and this is the format I will need to have.